# Science/engineering journals with high impact factor

Tags: 3d-models

What are some science/engineering journals on the topic of 3D printing with high impact factor? To publish a paper about the analysis of 3D models before printing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this one is acceptable: [Additive Manufacturing](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/additive-manufacturing)

It has an `11.632` Impact Factor.

Also, it has the *preprint* feature mentioned [here](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/additive-manufacturing/2214-8604/guide-for-authors):

> In support of Open Science, this journal offers its authors a free
> preprint posting service. Preprints provide early registration and
> dissemination of your research, which facilitates early citations and
> collaboration.
>
> During submission to Editorial Manager, you can choose to release your
> manuscript publicly as a preprint on the preprint server SSRN once it
> enters peer-review with the journal. Your choice will have no effect
> on the editorial process or outcome with the journal. ...
>
> You will be notified via email when your preprint is posted online and
> a Digital Object Identifier (DOI) is assigned. Your preprint will
> remain globally available free to read whether the journal accepts or
> rejects your manuscript.

Comment: Maybe related: https://www.experimental-history.com/p/the-rise-and-fall-of-peer-review

Comment: Maybe related too: https://www.experimental-history.com/p/the-dance-of-the-naked-emperors